# How to upload Android App Bundle (.aab) over 150MB to Google Play

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, google-play, release

I'm developing an app with React Native. But when generate .aab file to upload to Google Play Console (its size is about 370MB), I met *Your App Bundle contains the following configurations where the initial install would exceed the maximum size of 150 MB*. I found that my base is over 150MB (limit of GG), so any body can help me with *How to split app's assets and delivery it after
user installed it* or any way can help to upload my app. My app doesn't (and can't) use a host. Thankyou!

[image]

Comment: if my answer helped you or if it is correct according to your question, please, considere accepting it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can not upload files greater then that exceed 150MB as it's described in the documentation:

> Publishing with Android App Bundles helps your users to install your app with the smallest downloads possible and increases the **compressed download size limit to 150 MB**.

https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle#size_restrictions

Answer (score 0):

Try reducing the size. Can't exceed the limit

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33901876)